# Making app notch-friendly causes letterboxing on api 26 Galaxy S8 that doesn't have a notch

Tags: android, user-interface, fullscreen, compatibility

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/better-programming/making-notch-friendly-apps-for-android-75776272be5c
Created a folder values-v28
Copied my styles.xml which contained this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And added the line thats supposed to make my app ignore the notch. So the code in styles.xml that is in folder values-v28 is:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

This solved the problem for devices that have a notch. However this modification caused letterboxing on Galaxy S8  with Android 8 (API 26). Before this modification it worked correctly in fullscreen. Im struggling to fix this because I can't debug on this device and I can't seem to reproduce this problem in emulators. Galaxy S8 doesn't have a notch and API 26 shouldn't know about them. And adding code to values-v28 shouldn't affect Android 8 right?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.02"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Flags in onCreate:

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was unique to Samsung devices. It was caused by Game Tools as described here: [Game Tools letterboxing on Samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500063/game-tools-letterboxing-on-samsung-devices)